# Table Header and body widths not aligned

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have got a requirement to have a table to be of fixed width which contain both vertical and horizontal scroll bar.[image]

I have used "table-layout:fixed" to keep the width of table contained in the div and "width=100%". However if i dont use "display:grid" and "grid-auto-columns" property the table contents overlaps.

However, the table header and table body cell widths are not aligning.

I am using below css class

```
.newTbl {
display: grid;
border-collapse: collapse;
grid-auto-columns: 150px;
table-layout:fixed;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.newTbl thead {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    display: table-header-group
}

.newTbl thead tr td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.newTbl tbody tr td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}


.newTbl tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.newTbl tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

And my HTML code looks like this

```
                    <div
                                style="width: 100%; overflow: scroll; height: 350px; word-wrap: break-word">

                                <table class="newTbl" id="QueryTable"
                                    style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; white-space: nowrap;">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakvasdadasdasdasdadadasdasdasdasdasda</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakvasdadasdasdasdadadasdasdasdasdasda</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>

                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakvasdadasdasdasdadadasdasdasdasdasda</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>
                                            <td>aaskjdjksdhakv</td>


                                        </tr>                   

                                    </tbody>

                                </table>

                            </div>
```

Comment: The `thead` row (tr) does not dictate the width of the `tbody` rows (trs) given the CSS provided

Comment: @RandyCasburn is there a way to do something similar to this?

Comment: Use CSS to style them consistently.

Comment: you need to choose your display layout, grid or table : example with grid https://jsfiddle.net/sm9yp58t/ or is it morelike https://jsfiddle.net/sm9yp58t/1/  where all tds are to be a direct child to the grid (<table>) ;)

Comment: but if take out "table-layout:fixed", the table is not fitting in the outer div width but goes beyond and thus creating a scroll bar on the page rather than on the div

Comment: you mean you set `grid-auto-columns: 150px;` but do not want this ? almost 30 columns in your example, you want them to shrink within a few hundred pixels ? I think i misunderstood your question :( table-layout:fixed only works with display:table/ HTML <table> BTW.